# Codeigniter on IIS web.config issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, iis

I am installing a site made in PHP/CodeIgniter 2 on a hosting server which unfortunately has IIS running, which I have no experience in.

Nothing is working except the homepage, all other pages are returning 404 errors.

Adding index.php to the url returns 500 - Internal server error (I have the index page config set to '' in the config.php file)

I tried also creating a web.config file thinking the issue might be from the redirects, but adding a web.config file stops even the homepage from working, even if the web.config file added is completely empty.

Help really appreciated.

Comment: did you check out this post ? http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/91954

Comment: Whenever I add a web.config file I start getting a 500 Internal Server error even on the homepage.

Comment: Then you have probably some errors in your web.config file. Check the error log.

Comment: I have been copying the web.config from several answers (here on stackoverflow), so I doubt I have an error in it. Also, I can't check the error log, I don't have remote access, I just have access via a control panel. Could it be the PHP version difference? But how come there are no PHP errors displaying then.

Comment: I managed to fix the 404 errors (Corrupted files from ftp upload...). However, the web.config file is still not working to remove index.php. I am creating the file in my codeigniter's root folder and I am using the code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965124/how-to-rewrite-the-index-php-of-codeigniter-on-windows-azure but still I get 500 internal server error on home page when I do so. Any tips? :S

Answer (score 1):

Check if the hosting server has Re-write module installed in it, that could be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you had installed URL Rewrite - 
http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

After you had installed the module you should able to see this icon (URL Rewrite) in your IIS Management.
[image: IIS - URL Rewrite]