# Codeigniter Remove index.php from Browser Url

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url, iis-8.5

I want to create a app url 'http://example.com'. But entering the url, it shows 'HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden'. when i have inserted 'index.php' at the last of url like 'http://example.com/index.php' the landing page is rendering in the browser
I have changed the

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com';

$config['index_page'] = '';
```

and

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

in config.php file. Then i have placed the .htaccess file in the codeigniter root folder along with application and system folder. Then in the .htaccess file i have coded with

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

I just want to remove the 'index.php' from the url. I am using IIS 8.5 web server.

Comment: Sorry that i can't give you an exact answer due to not having any experience with IIS. But there are several answers listed here. And the second answer worked for me.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445385/how-to-remove-index-php-in-codeigniters-path?lq=1

One more thing you might try though is editing the .htaccess a bit more

    "RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^(application|system|\.svn) index.php/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]"

Comment: I already that way, but didn't work. Does apache and iis works in the same way

Comment: Seems not:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25439087/how-to-remove-index-php-in-codeigniter-on-windows-server-and-iis

Try this then. It actually seems that you will also need URL Rewrite module and the spec (conf) will look different from apache.

Comment: What version of CI you using?

Comment: I edited the  .htaccess with your code "RewriteEngine on RewriteBase / RewriteRule ^(application|system|\.svn) index.php/$1 [L] RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]" and o/p is the same "HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden"

Comment: My codeigniter version - 3.0.4 latest version and iis version - 8.5

Comment: I have some htaccess here you can try https://github.com/riwakawebsitedesigns/htaccess_for_codeigniter make sure in main directory your htaccess file.

Comment: replace below line RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L] and check it

Comment: IIS does not use taccess so it's no use for him.

These resources will help your cause:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965124/how-to-rewrite-the-index-php-of-codeigniter-on-windows-azure

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25439087/how-to-remove-index-php-in-codeigniter-on-windows-server-and-iis

Comment: You can also check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url)

Comment: if i am using apache web server your(Skaranjit) post will be helpful but i am using iis

Comment: htaccess file
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

my site is working http://demo.crowdfundingscript.com/ 
config file
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
$config['index_page'] = '';

Comment: Do i have to change something in the index.php in the root folder

Comment: I am approaching the same issue... Using Code Igniter 3.1.7 with IIS 8.0 :( , I tried different customized rules provided from yall's htaccess and imported to we webconfig using URL Write but still not working. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  htaccess file
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

  my site is working http://demo.crowdfundingscript.com/ 
  config file
  $config['uri_protocol']   = 'AUTO';
   $config['index_page'] = '';
```

Comment: Still the same error shows. Do i have change the index.php file in the root

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line:-

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
to
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

also change your base url as below.

```
$config['base_url']    = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/';
```

Write your rules as below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Hope it will work for you :)

Comment: It also resulted the same.

Comment: why changing "$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';" to "$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';"

Answer (score 0):

In config.php,

remove index.php in $config['index_page']

For ex :

$config['index_page'] = '';