# A custom filter or module, such as URLScan, restricts access to the file

Tags: php, codeigniter

I developed a website using the Codeigniter Framework.It is working fine in my localhost.And I uploaded the code to server.The server is IIS server. The home page is working fine (e.g.www.test.com). But for inner page (e.g. www.test.com/controller_name/about) it shows an error in server , like - HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal. You are using apache .htaccess file with rewrite rules, but IIS don't work with htaccess.
You have to set these rewrite rules in IIS web.config file.

Simple google search would help:
[How to rewrite the index.php of Codeigniter on Windows Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965124/how-to-rewrite-the-index-php-of-codeigniter-on-windows-azure)