# How to remove index.php from url (Code Igniter) using IIS 8.0 server

Tags: php, codeigniter, iis, codeigniter-3

I downloaded Code Igniter 3.1.7 and am hosting my website on IIS 8. However; I am currently at a stop due to an irritating problem which I have been trying to solve.

My goal is to remove 'index.php' from url when trying to access a controller.

> Example: http://localhost/welcome instead of
>   http://localhost/index.php/welcome

Since IIS does not use the htaccess file to create a rule to remove 'index.php' from url. An alternative I tried to do is to use the URL Write add-on provided by IIS.

[image]

After I hit **Apply**. The web.config file is created:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{R:1}" pattern="^(index\.php|assets|images|js|css|uploads|favicon.png)" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="%(REQUEST_FILENAME)" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="%(REQUEST_FILENAME)" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.php/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Then I went to application/config/config.php file and changed these variables:

`$config['base_url'] = '';` to `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/';`
  `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';` to `$config['index_page'] = '';`

Afterwards, I try to access using http://localhost/welcome , But I get this message:

> 404 - File or directory not found. The resource you are looking for
>   might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily
>   unavailable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965124/how-to-rewrite-the-index-php-of-codeigniter-on-windows-azure

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rewrite the index.php of Codeigniter on Windows Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965124/how-to-rewrite-the-index-php-of-codeigniter-on-windows-azure)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

in you `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /your_subfolder

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

in `application/config/config.php`

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

**update**
sorry i didn't see that you use IIS 8.0 server

see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig

Answer (score 0):

First set your URL Helper here `$autoload['helper'] = array();` in application/config/autoload.php

Then set your Base URL here like `$config['base_url'] = ''` Like this

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/example_project'
```

OR

```
$root=(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https://" : "http://").$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$root.= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '',  
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url'] = $root; //$root is your codeigniter project name i.e. eCommerce, example_project
```

Now run your application `http://localhost/project-folder-name`

Answer (score 0):

Frist time be sure that `$config['index_page] = '';`

After that try this `.htdocs`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Index.php remove and HTTP to https redirect in CodeIgniter. make 
 web.conig file and put code.


 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <configuration>
      <system.webServer>
          <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
               <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>
               <rewrite>
               <rules>
               <rule name="Rule" stopProcessing="true">
               <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
               <conditions>
               <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" 
               ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
               <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
              <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/favicon.ico$" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
       </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
   </rule>
   <!-- redirect non http to https  -->
  <rule name="www redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^[^\.]+\.[^\.]+$" />
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" />
 </rule>
 <rule name="www redirect https" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^[^\.]+\.[^\.]+$" />
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" />
       </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" />
     </rule>
      <!-- redirect non http to https  -->
    </rules>
   </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>

   <system.web>
      <customErrors mode="Off"/>
      <compilation debug="true"/>
   </system.web>
```